# Error: Failed to read source code Caused by: stream did not contain valid UTF-8

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I got a React project from GitHub, npm install, and ran it without any problems. But if you change the English in the html tag in jsx to Chinese, you will report an error, and I don't know how to change it after checking it for a long time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kSI7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUEpy.png)

The URL of this project as follow
[Source code](https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_metaverse)

I'm trying to debug and inspiring it will be run normally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: and also add chinese characters in question that causes problem